# Lock Cells to Certain People But Give Access to others in a Live Excel Online Worksheet

Tags: office-365, excel-services, office-web-apps

My company has switched from Google Docs to SharePoint and Office 365. One of the things that we need to be able to do is have a collaborative live/dynamic spreadsheet that give lock some cells to some people and give access to others. This was capable on Google Docs; can I do this on SharePoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your Excel Online Spreadsheet, and select to edit the spreadsheet in Excel (not Excel Online).
2. On the REVIEW tab select *Allow Users to Edit Ranges* in the Changs Group
3. Click *New* and select cells to restrict
4. Click *Permissions...* and chose the group that are allowed to edit (and select Allow).
5. Click *OK* to save the setting and save your Excel Online Workbook.

[image]

Comment: im trying to test this scenario in SharePoint 2013 . two users can open file in excel web app and edit cells simultaneously but this in not worked. any of three limited active directory accounts edit anywhere they want and not applied any restrictions!! any suggestion?? one of users not admin. one of users is SharePoint Farm admin.

Comment: You should lock your file First with "Protect Sheet". Then you allow users to edit certain ranges. You can look in the replies of this topic https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cell-protection-excel-online/1699cce2-0254-49e6-8532-3a4f013e810c . But I had no success with it...